# How to count todo list in doxygen ?

Tags: doxygen, todo

I'm going to display the count of **todo lists** on MainPage. Is there any special command for getting information of todo list ?

```
/*! \mainpage My Personal Index Page
 *
 * ToDo List = 100 
 * Bug List = 30
 *
 * etc...
 */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In doxygen there are not statistics available for the number of `\todo` commands used. 
A way to accomplish it would be externally get the number of `\todo` e.g. in case of *nix (or windows extended with the required commands through Cygwin or GNU) by means of `grep -c -w "[\\@]todo" -r <directory>`. The output can be redirected into an alias (see the doxygen configuration file (Doxyfile), tag `ALIASES`) or an input file (to be used as a sperate file or by means of `\includedoc`).